# Parsing Strings to Timestamps in AWS Athena

Tags: string, datetime, parsing, amazon-athena

The source data I am working in AWS Athena shows activity by time. The time is stored in string format. I want to convert the string into timestamps so I can do a few calculations on the data.

Two example values in the string_time field are:

1. 2020-12-07 11:00:02 AM -06:00
2. 2020-12-07 2:54:46 PM -06:00

I've tried to convert these to timestamps by using

```
parse_datetime(substr(string_time, 1, 22), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

or

```
parse_datetime(substr(string_time, 1, 22), '%Y-%m-%d %r)
```

but I keep getting errors like

> ```
> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Illegal pattern component: i
> ```

Or:

> ```
> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Illegal pattern component: r
> ```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Presto, `parse_datetime()` supports Java time formats. Since you are using MySQL's format specifiers, you want `date_parse()` instead.

So:

```
date_parse(substr(string_time, 1, 22), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! I had assumed that I could only use dates with date_parse. I added a trim around the substring to take out the extra space when the hour was single digit and not two digits. The query I finally used is date_parse(trim(substr(string_time, 1, 22)), '%Y-%m-%d %r')